# How do I extract texture from an obj file?

Tags: texturing

I am working on a project which requires me to extract a texture from a given obj file? I am new to blender. It would be helpful if anyone could explain me the steps to do so.

Comment: You could reprhase the question and ask how you can extract a texture after importing an .obj file.

Comment: @poor - Sorry, I had not provided detailed explanation regarding the issue. I have an .obj file which had texture on it. I had to just extract only the texture. I kind of got it working by using the bake option available in blender.

Comment: @stacker- Yes, sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: I'd like to help, but it's unclear what you are asking at the moment, because an obj file can't contain textures, the associated mtl file is linking the texture. Please provide more context and what exactly you want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @poor - I have a finger model which is in .obj format. Next step is to apply some texture on it. So after i render it, the texture is fixed on the finger model.  I am interested in importing the texture applied finger model and extracting the texture from that. I learnt that baking is the process which helps in extracting it. So i am currently working on that. It would be very helpful if you could provide me any other process. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for clarification - much better :) Asking multiple questions is not allowed here, so please try to rephrase this one and ask 2-3 new questions on the other topics you've mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Obj files don't contain textures. You have probably forgotten to download an additional file with your download, or the model doesn't include textures.